# Samsung device isn't connecting via USB cable for file transferring

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode

I am using a [Samsung Galaxy J8](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_j8-9205.php) device . My phone doesn't have any SD card. I was able to browse files of phone from my PC(ubuntu os) , even I could debug my app from android studio.  But suddenly I am not able to do so. When I connect my phone via USB to my PC , it is only charging . What I did so far is following.

1. Enable developer option and usb debugging , changed default usb configuration to file transfer and image transfer and MIDI .
2. Restarted my phone.
3. Restarted my PC .
4. Change of USB cable and port .
5. At last factory reset .

After trying all above things , still I can't connect to phone via usb cable .

I think my pc , usb cable , usb port are working fine . Because when I connected another device , it shows me the following dialog .

[image]

I used to see the same dialog for my phone, but right now,as I mentioned, my phone doesn't show me such dialog.